# Why was my edit removing links to movie scenes on YouTube rejected?

Tags: discussion, editing

I [suggested an edit](https://literature.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12478) to a question which contained 2 links to movie scenes on YouTube by accounts which do not seem to be authorized to post the footage publicly. The first video has already been taken down.

I thought it would improve the quality of the post if the links were to be removed, since the second video will also be likely taken down. However, my edit was rejected.

The reviewer has approved a lot more edit suggestions than he has rejected, so this makes me think that there must have been some valid reason for rejecting my edit. However, with one of the links already leading to a deleted video, I do not understand it.

**Edit**: Looking at it again, I realize that I had forgotten to remove the links from the bottom of the markdown, but I guess that could have been improved by the reviewer instead of rejecting the edit.

Comment: Apologies. I rejected it too hastily.

Comment: For what it's worth, I also saw this edit but, unsure what to do, "Skip"ped it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a valid edit after all. It seems the editor rejected it too hastily and the fact that I missed removing the URLs from the bottom of the markdown probably did not help.

I see that the edit has been made now.